# The callback was already called - css-loader - Angular

Tags: angular, npm, node-modules, npm-install, css-loader

I am getting this error while deploying the project to google cloud. It is working fine on my local end but when I try to deploy the project it occurs.

> Step #0 - "Build": [0m[91mCompiling ngx-material-file-input : es2015
> as esm2015
>
> Step #0 - "Build": [0m[91mCompiling ngx-toastr : es2015 as esm2015
>
> Step #0 - "Build":
> [0m[91m/ng-app/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:106
> Step #0 - "Build":            throw new Error("callback(): The callback was
> already called.");
>
> Step #0 - "Build":                  ^
>
> Step #0 - "Build":  Step #0 - "Build": Error: callback(): The callback
> was already called. Step #0 - "Build":     at context.callback
> (/ng-app/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:106:10)
>
> Step #0 - "Build":     at
> /ng-app/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/css-loader/dist/index.js:137:5
>
> Step #0 - "Build":     at processTicksAndRejections
> (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
>
> Step #0 - "Build":
>
> Step #0 - "Build": Node.js v17.1.0
>
> Step #0 - "Build": The command '/bin/sh -c npm run ng build -- --prod
> --output-path=dist' returned a non-zero code: 1 Finished Step #0 - "Build" ERROR ERROR: build step 0 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker"
> failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1
>
> Step #0 - "Build": [0m

[Here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S69zm.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue. The issue was the typescript was updating automatically to the latest version which added a conflict between angular and typescript versions which resulted in this error on GCP.

Solution: Add this in the tsconfig.json file and then try again

```
"angularCompilerOptions": {
    "disableTypeScriptVersionCheck": true,
  }
```